# Use of IBMs Ball Pivoting Algorithm in application

Tags: software, ibm

I plan to use the ball pivoting algorithm (US6968299 B1) in a commercial application. Now I'm not sure if I would implement it how it is described in this patent or rather from another source (book, paper, website describing it).

However, since the method itself is patented, do I have to get the rights from IBM to use it even if I were to only use a description of the method from a website or book?

Comment: No one knows anything about this?

Answer (score 1):

A little late, but the answer is, if your algorithm uses all the steps of any claim in the patent, then you are infringing the patent.